# Show content of DIV by clicking on it if it has the same CLASS as ATTRUBUTE

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to achieve is: I have a few groups of DIVs with attribute 'rel' (dynamically created) and a DIV inside with the same class as the parents attribute.

```
<div class="quote-logos logo-94" rel="quote-94">
<div id="quote-94" style="display:none;">
    <div class="quote">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="author-name">-1</div>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="quote-logos logo-169" rel="quote-169">
<div id="quote-169" style="display:none;">
    <div class="quote">
        <p>Duis turpis tellus, porta vitae arcu ut, aliquet volutpat turpis.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="author-name">-2</div>
</div>
```

By clicking on the main DIV I want to add its content to the separate DIV.

```
 <div id="display"></div>
```

I have managed to get the attribute and alert it but cannot make the content of the parent DIV after click on it appended to

Can anyone please help? My fiddle is available below:

http://jsfiddle.net/KSaGe/2/

Please feel free to amend it... Note the attributes are dynamically created...

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/d6suD/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/KSaGe/5/

```
$('.quote-logos').click(function () {
     $("#display").html($(this).find('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).html());
});
```

Comment: Magic solution Tolgahan! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you're looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/KSaGe/2/

```
 $('.quote-logos').click(function () {
     $("#display").text($(this).find("p").text());
})
```